# Talend tmaps,mysqlconnection and tuniqrow issues

Tags: mysql, filter, talend, tmap

Hello i am very new to Talend, i am taking classes on the matter and it is a very simple data filtering software , but i come across some issues but my instructors have not come online again since Thursday , so since i don't want to stay with these issues for too long i want to ask here how to do this stuff (i already look it up on the main source page and couldn't find answers to this)

- How can i give multiple inputs to a tMap from multiple tUniqRows or multiple tRowGenerators? it is not letting me do it and i find it pretty weird, it should let me.
- Why is it important to create a tMysqlConnection prior running the job? i mean without it, it connects perfectly (with it too but i don't know why it is important)
- How can i validate that there can be only 2 instances of an specific value for a row? seems like tUniqRow does this but halfway.

Thanks a lot for reading hope you can answer my questions, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for later questions: It is always easier to answer with a picture of your job layout.

- `tMap` multiple inputs: just connect a second data source when the first is already connected to the `tMap`. It should use this as a "lookup" source and you can join the data.
- It is not *important* to create a `tMySQLConnection`. It is rather a smart step if all your processing should happen within a transaction. Also, you open only one connection to your database - if you iterate over thousands of rows, this could become an issue if you wouldn't use just one connection and commit from time to time
- I didn't understand what `tUniqRow` does halfway. You could always use a `tFilterRow` and put some checks into it or just sum every entity and ignore those which are more / show an error message

Comment: thanks for your answers ! , however in my talend for some reason the tMap does not want to accept more than one input from tUniqRow or tFilterRow its rather weird.

Comment: Again, it is hard to help without knowing your job layout. Think about adding a picture to your post.